# GWT Not showing root call trace on click exception

Tags: java, exception, gwt

When handling a click event and an uncaught exception is thrown the console does not show the actual line of code where the exception is triggered. Instead, it looks like this:

```
Throwable.java:121 Uncaught Error: com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'getNotificationsShortcuts_0_g$' of null
    at iOi_g$.cve_g$ [as createError_0_g$] (Throwable.java:121)
    at iOi_g$.mve_g$ [as initializeBackingError_0_g$] (Throwable.java:113)
    at iOi_g$.Yue_g$ (Throwable.java:74)
    at iOi_g$.Cve_g$ (Exception.java:33)
    at iOi_g$.Kve_g$ (RuntimeException.java:33)
...
```

If I try/catch the code where the exception is thrown and print the caught exception by getting all the StackTraceElement items from e.getStackTrace(), it seems that the stack trace is displayed correctly (the root in my lines of code is displayed):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNotificationsShortcuts_0_g$' of null
    at VCn_g$.fDn_g$ [as loadSavedShurtcuts_0_g$] (EMaterialNotificationsHeaderView.java:483)
    at BCn_g$.HCn_g$ [as loadSavedShurtcuts_0_g$] (EMaterialNotificationsHeader.java:37)
    at fFn_g$.gFn_g$ [as build_0_g$] (SDemoNotificationsHeader.java:51)
...
```

Is there a way to show set the logs so that the root call trace of the exception is displayed correctly when an event is triggered?

Answer (score 1):

If an exception is directly caught, you will see the full stack trace. If an exception simply wraps another single exception, generally you'll see the stack trace as well.

But the UmbrellaException indicates that some event was going off when that exception was thrown. The event didn't just stop because of the exception (which would then cause other handlers to miss out on it), but instead the exception was noted, and the other handlers invoked. Once they were all finished, an UmbrellaException gets thrown, containing all of the exceptions that happened during the course of trying to fire that event.

Often this will only wrap a single exception, but the result is the same - the umbrella exception informs you that something went wrong, and the event finished informing all of its handlers, and then this was thrown to say *that* something went wrong.

If you are seeing this in your UnCaughtExceptionHandler (UCEH), then there was no try/catch around the fireEvent call itself.

---

Whether you catch it in the UCEH or in some other try/catch, once you test if it is an UmbrellaException, you can call `exception.getCauses()` to read all of the exceptions that occurred, and individually log each of them.